# VBA leyendo un JSON

Tags: json, excel, webservice, vba

Estoy intentando leer un Json que me devuelve un servicio web y mostrar los datos en un Excel utilizando VBA. La llamada la hago con esto:

```
Dim hReq As Object    
Dim strUrl As String
strUrl = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=db3927718fdf4a45ad6110811182009&q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5"

Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .send
    End With
```

Si luego de esto pongo

```
MsgBox hReq.responseText
```

me muestra el Json sin problemas. El Json sería este (está recortado ya que es muy grande, pero para mi pregunta con esto basta):

```
{
"data": {
    "request": [
        {
            "type": "City",
            "query": "London, United Kingdom"
        }
    ],
    "current_condition": [
        {
            "observation_time": "01:43 PM",
            "temp_C": "21",
            "temp_F": "70",
            "weatherCode": "116",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
                {
                    "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"
                }
            ],
            "weatherDesc": [
                {
                    "value": "Partly cloudy"
                }
            ],
            "windspeedMiles": "21",
            "windspeedKmph": "33",
            "winddirDegree": "220",
            "winddir16Point": "SW",
            "precipMM": "0.1",
            "humidity": "60",
            "visibility": "10",
            "pressure": "1010",
            "cloudcover": "75",
            "FeelsLikeC": "21",
            "FeelsLikeF": "70"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Si en mi código VBA pongo a continuación

```
Dim JSON As Object
Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(hReq.responseText)
For Each item In JSON("data")
    MsgBox item
Next item
```

Me va mostrando ventanas con los valores "request" y "current_condition". Pero a mi lo que me interesaría es, por ejemplo, escribir en la celda (1,1) el valor que aparece en "value" que está dentro de "weatherDesc" y a su vez dentro de "current_condition" (lo que quiero que aparezca en la celda es "Partly cloudy"). Lo estoy intentando con el siguiente código:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Hoja1")
ws.Cells(1, 1) = JSON("data")("current_condition")(0)("weatherDesc")(0)("value")
```

Pero me sale un error: Se ha producido el error '9' en tiempo de ejecución: subíndice fuera de intervalo

Por favor alguien me podría decir como hago para escribir dicho dato? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesita `For Each`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CurrentWeatherDescription()
    Dim hReq As Object, JSON As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Const URL As String = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=db3927718fdf4a45ad6110811182009&q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5"

    Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
    End With

    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(hReq.responseText)
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = JSON("data")("current_condition")(1)("weatherDesc")(1)("value")
End Sub
```

---

Ruta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Lo logré! El código correcto sería:

```
Dim strUrl As String
Dim hReq As Object  
Dim JSON As Object
Dim salida As Object  
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

strUrl = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=db3927718fdf4a45ad6110811182009&q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5"

Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
With hReq
    .Open "GET", strUrl, False
    .send
End With

Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(hReq.responseText)

For Each salida In JSON("data")("current_condition")
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = salida("weatherDesc")(1)("value")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que te está dando es porque `JSON("data")("current_condition")(0)("weatherDesc")(0)("value")` no existe. Estas parseando el contenido del JSON en un objeto por lo que este no va a tener las propiedas enlazadas del contenido de JSON, deberías parsearlo a una clase tipada para poder acceder a las propiedades. Diría que lo único que tiene tu object JSON es un string con todo el contenido del json que redibes del Webservice.

Te recomiendo usar otra tecnología en vez de VBA, yo he trabajado mucho programando Excel con C# con las librerias Closed y Open XML pra el tipo de cosas que estas haciendo. Puedes descargar Visual Studio Community gratuitamente y este programa te va a permitir tener muchas más herramientas para todo el proceso de programación. C# es mucho más utilizado que VB por la comunidad de desarrolladores.